# How to declare multiple deadline timer in class definition?

Tags: boost, deadline-timer

I have managed to declare one deadline timer in a class.

```
class myTimerService
{
public:
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    myTimerService():t0(ioService){}
private:
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t0;
};
```

so the construct is able to construct the t0.
How do I modify it to have another deadline_timer t1. How would the construct look like for following?

```
class myTimerService
{
public:
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    myTimerService()-------????
private:
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t0;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t1;
};
```

Comment: myTimerService():t0(ioService), t1(ioService) {}  perhaps?

Comment: that worked, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As the commenter said, base & member initializer list is comma-separated:

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>
class myTimerService {
  public:
    boost::asio::io_service ioService;
    myTimerService() : t0(ioService), t1(ioService) {}

  private:
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t0;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t1;
};
```

However, I'd suggest [NSMI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46510055/correct-way-to-initialize-class-member-objects-that-have-parameters):

```
#include <boost/asio.hpp>

class myTimerService {
    boost::asio::io_service     ioService;
    boost::asio::deadline_timer t0{ioService}, t1{ioService};
};
```